# Parallax game base - Chrome (and probably others) - performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parallax

http://www.perandersen.no/sandbox/robot/

I have tried writing a game base for a side scroller adventure/puzzle game. I have some performance issues in Chrome and it looks buggy in IE and Safari, but nice in FF and in Opera.

Is it possible to make the code more efficient? Is there another way of achieving the parallax effect? It really annoys me that this isn't working the same way in all browsers...

Answer (score 1):

For the backdrop, looks like you need to specify 'background-attachment: fixed;' and have javascript move it *with* the page instead of *against* the page to avoid that jerky effect. The rest looked alright. See here for further explanation: http://thelastdeveloper.tumblr.com/post/20536873534/fix-parallax-jumping-jerky-hinky-jinky-scrolling-on